# rails_admin when editing a belongs_to association display user name instead of User id

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

I have a Rails 3.2.21 app using Rails Admin.

I've written an initializer on a specific model `ClockEvent` for all of my actions.  In particular in the list/show/edit actions I want to display actual user's full name instead of the User #1.

From the code below, I have list and show working with `pretty_value`, but I'm stumped when it comes to my edit action how to get the dropdown/search fields to display the User full_name (which is a field in User.rb) instead of User #1.

Here's my code below.

user.rb

```
has_many :clock_events
```

clock_event.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

config/initializers/rails_admin.rb

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.authorize_with do |controller|
    unless current_user.role == 'admin'
      redirect_to main_app.root_path
      flash[:error] = "You are not an admin"
    end
  end

  config.model 'ClockEvent' do
  configure :user, :belongs_to_association
  configure :station, :belongs_to_association
    list do
      field :clock_in
      field :clock_out
      field :user do
        pretty_value do
            value.try(:full_name)
        end
      end
      field :station do
        pretty_value do
            value.try(:station_name)
        end
      end
      field :created_at
      field :updated_at
    end

    show do
      field :clock_in
      field :clock_out
      field :user do
        pretty_value do
            value.try(:full_name)
        end
      end
      field :station do
        pretty_value do
            value.try(:station_name)
        end
      end
      field :comment
      field :hr_comment
      field :created_at
      field :updated_at
    end

    edit do
      field :clock_in
      field :clock_out
      field :user do
        pretty_value do
            value.try(:user).try(:full_name)
        end
      end
      field :station do
        pretty_value do
            value.try(:station_name)
        end
      end
      field :comment
      field :hr_comment
      field :created_at
      field :updated_at
    end
    export do; end
    create do; end
    update do; end
 end
end
```

As you can see, I'm also doing this for another belongs_to model for station, but I'm focusing on the user model and how to get the edit fields to search by username or fullname instead of displaying User #1 which is pretty worthless.

If you have any suggestions or solutions, I'd really appreciate it.  The rails_admin wiki is not as helpful for this specific type of thing and I've poured over it already.

If you need more clarification or my question/code is not clear enough, please ask.

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out myself.  I needed to call enum on the `user_id` and `station_id` field then a collect to map out the names to ids.  This works!

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.authorize_with do |controller|
    unless current_user.role == 'admin'
      redirect_to main_app.root_path
      flash[:error] = "You are not an admin"
    end
  end

  config.model 'ClockEvent' do
    list do
      field :clock_in
      field :clock_out
      field :user do
        searchable :full_name
        pretty_value do
            value.try(:full_name)
        end
      end
      field :station do
        searchable :station_name
        pretty_value do
            value.try(:station_name)
        end
      end
      field :created_at
      field :updated_at
    end

    show do
      field :clock_in
      field :clock_out
      field :user do
        pretty_value do
            value.try(:full_name)
        end
      end
      field :station do
        pretty_value do
            value.try(:station_name)
        end
      end
      field :comment
      field :hr_comment
      field :created_at
      field :updated_at
    end

    edit do
      field :clock_in
      field :clock_out
      field :user_id, :enum do
        enum do
          User.employee.collect {|p| [p.full_name, p.id]}
      end
    end
      field :station_id, :enum do
        enum do
          Station.all.collect {|p| [p.station_name, p.id]}
      end
    end
      field :comment
      field :hr_comment
      field :created_at
      field :updated_at
    end
    export do; end
    create do; end
    update do; end
 end

 config.model 'CallUnit' do
  visible false
 end

 config.model 'CallSpecialEquipment' do
  visible false
 end

  config.model 'CallsFacilities' do
  visible false
 end
end
```